# How to display boxes / images as an when it loaded with jquery media boxes library

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have integrated the Jquery mediabox (http://www.castlecodeweb.com/mediaboxes/documentation/index.html) for representing the image gallery.

For few images it working fine but when there are thousands of images than it waiting for all images to be load first into the browser and than after it starting to display the images.

So due to this holding behavior of this library user have to wait for more than 5 mins first time until all the images will get load first.

So can you please share if there is any option available like when first few boxes/images loaded than let's start to display instead of waiting for all the boxes/images ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this problem like that, in first time you need to load in mediaboxes only just 4-5 images, to fill view on first open page. After, you need to make jquery scripts on event on scroll to load more images and add (insert) it to mediaboxes.

If you read documentation [here](http://www.castlecodeweb.com/mediaboxes/documentation/index.html#methods) method insert, you will understand what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for your input. let me try this out.